# Как проверить, пуст ли ListView?

Tags: android, listview

Как убедиться в том, что все записи `ListView` удалены и вывести текст "*ListView пуст.*"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Методом `getCount()` узнаете количество элементов в листе и в зависимости от того какое их количество - выполняете соответствующие действия:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findById(R.id.list_id);
int count = list.getCount();
```

Если `count = 0` - выводить сообщение!

Comment: Большое спасибо, сделал - все работает. Добавлю, что для работы с удалением и переходами по разным активити я еще такую же проверку сделал в методе onStart(), чтобы при добавлении и возвращении на нужную активити происходило исчезновение надписи.

Answer (score 4):

Для реализации функции сообщения, что список пуст  `ListView` имеет стандартный метод `setEmptyView(View)`:

Можно установить произвольное `View` (в данном примере `TextView`), что список пуст из кода:

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
View empty = findViewById(R.id.emptyList);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setEmptyView(empty);
```

разметка:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/listLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/emptyList"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="EMPTY!"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Через `ViewStub` вы можете вывести целый `Layout`, который будет достаточно сложно оформлен: форматированный текст, картинка и тп.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/listLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/emptyList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout="@layout/emptyLayout" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Либо в случае, если используется наследование от `ListActivity`, воспользоваться системным ID (`@id/android:empty`) для сообщения о том, что список пуст. Данный ID следует назначить `View` на разметке, который покажет сообщение:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/ListLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```